# check if 2 bitmaps are the same

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to do a memory game in android studio and i have the following code but it isn't working. can someone tell me why/ how to fix it?

```
 public void onClick1(View view) {
            if(counter<2) {
                button1[0][0].setBackgroundResource(pics[0][0]);
                clicked[0][0]=true;
                if(counter==1) {
                    for(int i= clicked.length -1; i>0;i--) {
                        for (int j=clicked[i].length -1; j>0; j--){
                            if(clicked[i][j]==true){
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)button1[0][0].getBackground()).getBitmap();
                                Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)button1[i][j].getBackground()).getBitmap();
                                if(bitmap == bitmap2)
                                {
                                    button1[i][j].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    button1[0][0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                                else {
                                    button1[0][0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                                    clicked[0][0]=false;
                                    button1[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                                    clicked[i][j]=false;
                                    counter=0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    counter++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is not working? Does it crash with an error? If yes post the errors. If it doesn't crash post the expected result and the real result. Just "not working" is not helpful at all.

Comment: Please provide exactly what you problem is. ``Not working`` is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 4):

For `Bitmap` objects you can use the method [`Bitmap.sameAs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)) to compare if 2 bitmaps are the same.

> **boolean sameAs(Bitmap other)**
>
> Given another bitmap, return true if it has the same dimensions,
>   config, and pixel data as this bitmap. If any of those differ, return
>   false. If other is null, return false.

So instead of:

```
if(bitmap == bitmap2)
```

Use:

```
if(bitmap.sameAs(bitmap2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am comparing two `Bitmap` using [Bitmap.sameAs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)) method and it says on docs :

```
/**
 *  Given another bitmap, return true if it has the same dimensions, config,
 *  and pixel data as this bitmap. If any of those differ, return false.
 *  If other is null, return false.
 */
```

For example :

```
Bitmap dogeBitmap;
Bitmap duckBitmap;

if(dogeBitmap.sameAs(duckBitmap)) {
  // they are same
}
```

If you are creating bitmaps manually make sure at least they have same config to compare them visually

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this  to compare Bitmap:

```
private fun compareBitMap(bitmap: Bitmap, otherBitmap: Bitmap): Boolean {
    val bitMapAreSame = bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap) &&
            (bitmap.width == otherBitmap.width &&
                    bitmap.width == otherBitmap.width &&
                    bitmap.height == otherBitmap.height &&
                    bitmap.byteCount == otherBitmap.byteCount &&
                    bitmap.density == otherBitmap.density)
    bitmap.recycle()
    otherBitmap.recycle()
    return bitMapAreSame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do a hard check like this:

```
private fun compareBitMap(bitmap: Bitmap, otherBitmap: Bitmap): Boolean {
    val bitMapAreSame = bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap) &&
            (bitmap.width == otherBitmap.width &&
                    bitmap.width == otherBitmap.width &&
                    bitmap.height == otherBitmap.height &&
                    bitmap.byteCount == otherBitmap.byteCount &&
                    bitmap.density == otherBitmap.density)
    bitmap.recycle()
    otherBitmap.recycle()
    return bitMapAreSame
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if there's an `arrayByte` which is the same by this

```
public boolen isSameBitmap(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream1);
   byte[] byteArrayBitmap1 = stream.toByteArray();

   ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bmp2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream2);
   byte[] byteArrayBitmap2 = stream.toByteArray();

  return Arrays.equals(byteArrayBitmap1, byteArrayBitmap2);
}
```